# how to remove "unsafe" added to img src

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular data binding on img src so my code is

```
<img src="{{ baseURL + dish.image }}">
```

and the result is in the page

```
<img  src="unsafe: http://localhost:3000/images/zucchipakoda.png">
```

I want to remove the "unsafe:" to let the image show.

[the result i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvQIm.png)

[image]

Comment: What is the baseurl contain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please inject DomSanitizationService in constructor

example :

```
constructor( private dom: DomSanitizationService) {}
photoURL(imageUrl) {
  return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageUrl);
}
```

OR without function photoUrl u can try it

```
<img src="dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageUrl)"/>
```

> note :  DomSanitizer for(angular7+) and DomSanitizationService (angular2+)